# Include a zip file in the Maven generated jar

Tags: java, maven

I need to include a zip file in the src/test/resource dir  in the maven generated jar .
Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Using maven assembly plugin you can control the archive creation with very high flexibility.

Comment: What generated jar? A jar for test related code is not created unless you specifically ask for it. Perhaps you could provide a more complete description of what you're trying to accomplish. Is this zip file only consumed by test code in this module? A code fragment showing how it is used in a test will help provide a better answer.

Comment: yes the zip file is only for test purpose only. The method I test does some specific operations on a given zip file and for testing I have to provide a very specific zip file. After completing my project I want to include that file along with my project in order for other people to be able to pull it from the repo and test it with the exact same zip file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in [isapir's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54915662/1036310), you should ideally place the zip file under `src/main/resource` if that needs to be included in your jar file. But if you really need to include it from your `src/test/resource` folder, you can use [build-helper-maven-plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/) as below:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>add-resource</id>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>add-resource</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <include>ABC.zip</include>
                        <directory>src/test/resource</directory>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put the zip archive in the `src/main/resources` directory and not in src/test/resource.

If you want to have more control then check out the Maven Resources Plugin documetation: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/index.html

Comment: As stated in the link you provided :"The difference is that the main resources are the resources associated to the main source code while the test resources are associated to the test source code."  The zipFile is only needed for the test that is why I placed it in the test/resources / dir . Should I change it ?

Comment: If it's only needed for tests then are you sure that you want it in the target JAR?  Usually if used only in tests then it should not be deployed in the generated JAR.  Perhaps you can update your question and clarify why you want to deploy a test ZIP resource

Comment: @N.Kokkoris test classes and resource do not leave the module unless a very serious effort is done.

Comment: @isapir I want to include it in because I want the test case to always run with this file, meaning that other colleagues  pulling this project for the repo to also get that test file .

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen, meaning ?